# How can I close the microphone/camera popup in Python / Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I want to click block. I tried this:

```
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss();
```

However it says that there is no alert open. I think it's not considered as an alert?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the **`Microphone/Camera`** popup you can use the following `arguments` from **`ChromeOptions`** `Class`:

- Java solution:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("allow-file-access-from-files");
  options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
  options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); 
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```