# How to allow permissions to content in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, user-permissions

I am in stuck and cannot allow using camera and microphone in WebDriver:

[image]

How can I handle this by WebDriver? I did not find any helpful info on the Internet related to this.

Thanks in advance.

PS: [How can I close the microphone/camera popup in Python / Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716814/how-can-i-close-this-popup-in-python-selenium) -- is not solving my case (I don't need "fake").

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628904/accept-permission-request-in-chrome-using-selenium ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close this 'popup' in Python / Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716814/how-can-i-close-this-popup-in-python-selenium)

Comment: @DebanjanB, no, it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allow/block the different contents though the preferences:

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,     # 1:allow, 2:block 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,  # 1:allow, 2:block 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,          # 1:allow, 2:block 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1         # 1:allow, 2:block 
  })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```