# How to allow or deny notification geo-location microphone camera pop up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to click on **Allow** button of access camera authentication pop up.

Here is the look of pop up.

[image: here]

Comment: What causes the pop up show?  what platform are you on?  what kind of application?  what have you tried?  Please give us some more context so that we have a better idea of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close the microphone/camera popup in Python / Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716814/how-can-i-close-the-microphone-camera-popup-in-python-selenium/47717362#47717362)

Comment: @BreaksSoftware The site i'm working on,needs my camera and mic. So, i want to **allow** this authentication pop up.                                                               i have tried with alert accept method or via switching window. But it is a authentication browser pop up.So, i don't think so it will help me out.

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes, it is simillar to that,Only thing I need to **Allow** the pop up instead of Block.

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried with the code:                                                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("allow-file-access-from-files");
options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);                                   
                                                                                                               
But it is opening new window and that allow camera method getting passed and failed to the next method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To **`Allow`** or **`Block`** the notification of **`Microphone`**, **`Camera`**, **`GeoLocation`**, **`Notification`** access using **`Selenium`** you have to use `ChromeOptions` Class as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
  })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I'm facing some error on below line using this code.It would be appreciated if you can help me :                                                                                                       
options.addArguments
   ( "prefs", { 
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic":1,        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera":1,
}  )

Comment: Can you update the Question with your current code block and the error stack trace?

Comment: I'm having syntax error as:                                                                             
           Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ":", invalid 
  AssignmentOperator
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
  variable                                                                                        
                    
      Over below line code:  opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,  
  })

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("allow-file-access-from-files");
options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);                                           **This Method helped me ;-)**

Comment: @DebanjanB, Could you plz point me out where I can have the list of experimental options flags?

Comment: @S.K.Venkat Checkout [Chromeoptions and setExperimentalOption code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465124/chromeoptions-and-setexperimentaloption-code/49469595#49469595)

Answer (score 2):

This java code helped me

```
public WebDriver initWebDriver() {
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
     options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
     prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 1);
     prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);
     prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1);
     prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
     options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
     System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER, DRIVER_PATH);
     return new ChromeDriver(options);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Browser.grantPermissions",
    {
        "origin": TARGET_URL    ,   # e.g https://www.google.com
        "permissions": ["geolocation", "audioCapture", "displayCapture", "videoCapture",
                        "videoCapturePanTiltZoom"]
    },
)
```