# Chromeoptions and setExperimentalOption code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to understand the meaning of following lines of code for setting up Chromeoptions in selenium code
Can someone explain its meaning and als provide some external link for further learning -:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete details :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
```

Through this line you are creating an object by the name **options** of [**ChromeOptions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) Class.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Here you have created a new [**Map**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) object by the name **prefs** where the *Key* and *Value* fields accepts *String* and *Object* type of data  and casted it to [**HashMap**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap).

```
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
```

In these three lines you have configured the [pref-names](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?sq=package:chromium&type=cs) within the *prefs* object.

```
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Finally in this line you are using the [setExperimentalOption](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setExperimentalOption-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method to set these experimental options (ChromeDriver options not yet exposed through the ChromeOptions API) within the *options* object.

Now you can use this *options* object of *ChromeOptions* Class to initialize the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* as follows :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

These are chrome browser preferences. You can set using options. You can find full list here in source code of chromium
https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup