# How to disable chrome notifications popup in python and selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to disable chrome notifications popup in python and selenium?

I tried:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But then also it shows notification...

[image: notifications popup image]

> I tried the same codes [answered
>   here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48017495/10306484) but then also I
>   am not able to disable the notifications!

Answer (score 2):

The selenium package has a `ChromeOptions` class, in which you can add many arguments. One of which is `'disable-notifications'`. You can pass that class to the driver class when initializing it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Please consider explain your approach though it pretty straight forward. Adding a few comment on explain the code and how it work in the case of OP would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

---

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\PycharmProjects\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()

---

This works with the right placement of code:
Click here for Image-->[ChromeOptions Pycharm Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfXk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can pass `disable-notifications` to your chrome options.

Here's an example I have using Javascript, should work the same with Python.

```
var o = new chrome.Options();

o.addArguments('user-data-dir=./chromeprofile');
o.addArguments('disable-infobars');
o.addArguments("disable-notifications");
o.setUserPreferences( { credentials_enable_service: false } );
```