# How to enable 'Mircophone' access in Edge browser using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge, microphone

I understand there are various flags/parameters you can pass using desired caps to enable access to camera, microphone, etc.

For instance on Chrome you can use ChromeOption and pass '**profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mi**' under '**prefs**'.

***I wish to enable the microphone access on Edge browser.*** I am not able to find any related information. Can somebody assist me here?

For Chrome you can enable the same like mentioned here-

[How to allow or deny notification geo-location microphone camera pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/how-to-allow-or-deny-notification-geo-location-microphone-camera-pop-up/48017495#48017495)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following preferences to allow camera, microphone in Edge Browser.

```
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setCapability("dom.webnotifications.enabled", 1);
options.setCapability("permissions.default.microphone", 1);
options.setCapability("permissions.default.camera", 1);
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I will try this out and confirm !! Would it be possible to know all the available Edge flags? Any offical Microsoft document?

Comment: No not having official Microsoft document, but I have tried this and working fine for me.

Comment: Are those 3 capabilities documented somewhere? Are they meant to be used with edge browser?

Comment: Not documented but  I have tried this and working fine for me