# Deny microphone access

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to access a webpage that asks for microphone [image: (like this one)], how do I deny it using python?
The library that I am using is *requests*, but I can use another one.

Thanks

Comment: _The library that I am using is requests_ How is that possible, since requests is just an HTTP library?

Comment: that 's what I am asking

Comment: My point is that it doesn't make much sense. You shared a screenshot of a popup on Chrome (?), it's unrelated.

Comment: I don 't know much about that library so I tought it may have some other things implemented.

Comment: What other things? There really isn't anything to do in the first place, requests doesn't care about microphone permissions.

Comment: that 's what I didn 't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kind of APIs (location, microphone, camera, etc) are using JavaScript, so basically only have effect if you are using a browser (or something very-very similar to a browser).

On the other hand, libraries like `requests` operates on HTTP and have nothing to do with JavaScript APIs. Basically you do not have to do anything, because the JavaScript from the site will not run, so there is nothing to allow or deny.

Comment: Thanks, so could be it possible to use the selenium library as the other answer told?

Comment: If you would like to *forcibly deny* it, then yes, that is possible through Selenium. If you are only interested not allowing it (e.g. the website cannot access your mic while you are scraping it), then you are good to go with what you have now.

Answer (score -1):

→ [Is this what you want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/how-to-allow-or-deny-notification-geo-location-microphone-camera-pop-up) ←
(bascially, you just need to use `Selenium` and his `ChromeOptions` Class