# how to set fake audio path in chrome for selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
audio_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'audio\01.wav')
print(audio_path)
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--reduce-security-for-testing")
options.add_argument('--allow-file-access-from-files')
options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=‪{}".format(audio_path))


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('')
```

but it is skill error:
[11532:17860:0428/172951.505:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(368)] Invalid audio output parameters received; using fake audio path. Channels: 0, Sample Rate: 0, Bits Per Sample:0, Frames Per Buffer: 0
why?

Comment: i user Google Chrome 66.0.3359.139

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close the microphone/camera popup in Python / Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716814/how-can-i-close-the-microphone-camera-popup-in-python-selenium)